# "Stack" UIViews within a UIViewController (iOS 7)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I am a noob iOS developer and I have a quick question in which I have been pulling my hair out for a couple of days.

To start I am not using the Interface Builder within XCode as I have been told that the best way to learn is by intially building everything through code.

With that said, I have a custom UIViewController in which I am adding subviews. My question is this, how do I automatically "stack" them when they have variable heights? What I mean by "stack" is the following:

```
|------------------------------------|
|                                    |
|      View 1 (variable height)      |
|                                    |
|------------------------------------|
|------------------------------------|
|                                    |
|      View 2 (variable height)      |
|                                    |
|------------------------------------|
|------------------------------------|
|                                    |
|      View 3 (variable height)      |
|                                    |
|------------------------------------|
```

Right now I am calculating the orgin/height of each in the overloaded "sizeToFit" function for each subview once all of them have been rendered. Some views contain UIWebView's in which I wait for them to load to calculate the height.

There has be be a more elegant way of doing this, no?

Any code examples would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You ready for [AutoLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and the [Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH3-SW1)?

Comment: Why aren't you using a `UITableViewController` for this?

Comment: Though previous two guys were right - you are also doing it right! I would recommend to start learning AutoLayout since it is really a time saver. And in iOS world the best way to live is to reuse standard components which fit your needs. In this particular case UITableView would fit well (you can set row height in tableview:heightForRow:atIndexPath:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Auto Layout!

What Auto Layout does is manage the UI layout for you, based on constraints you provide. For example, in the view hierarchy above, you'd want to have a constraint for the views' heights, and constraints between each view and finally constraints with the views' superview.

Since you are doing everyting in code, first thing you have to do is call `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:` on each view with the value of `NO`. This tells the layout system that you wish to use Auto Layout and set all constraints yourself.

Next you should provide constraints for all you views. Constraints come in several forms: constraints between the view and itself (height, width, etc.); constraints between a view and a peer - constraints between two views that share the same superview; and constraints between a view and its superview. The Auto Layout system does not like ambiguity, so you would have to provide constraints that leave no place to questions. For your example above, you would have to set up each view's height, its position within the superview and the distance between one view and another.

More advanced topics include intrinsic size, which would tell Auto Layout that your view may dynamically grow and shrink according to its content, and as it does, others react accordingly.

The easiest way to define constraints is using the visual format.

I recommend starting with these:

- [Apple's guide on Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [A good visual format guide](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/)
- [Apple's WWDC2012 introduction keynote on Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202)

---

A word on doing UI in code vs Interface Builder. Let me tell you, don't learn UI code for the sake of UI code. Come up with an idea, and start implementing the idea. Start with Interface Builder. You will slowly learn about how views work, how they are layout, how constraints work, how the layout engine uses constraints, etc. With Xcode 5, AutoLayout has become a joy to use, and with Xcode 5.1, things are even better. Start with Interface Builder, you will eventually get to the code, and learn, with time, everything you need to accomplish your task.

Learning should not be about "Oh, I know how to add views in code!"; learning should be "I know how to tackle a problem that I have to accomplish or overcome". If all your tasks can be completed using the Interface Builder tool, that's great. There's a problem you can't solve using IB? Even better, now you are learning about the inner workings of views and layout.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info and links! However, shouldn't setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints be set to "NO", that's what is says in the "A good visual format guide"?

Comment: @thiesdiggity Uhhm, yes indeed. Oops